# How to use match and blank

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

This very basic problem baffles me. From the documentation I do not understand the results of

```
MatchQ[{a, b}, {_, _}]
MatchQ[a*b, Times[_, _]]
MatchQ[a*b, Times[__, _]]
```

giving: True, False, True. 
What is the difference of blanks in the first and second case? What does the `BlankSequence` in the third case refer to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a good question! See, the pattern `Times[_, _]` immediately evaluates to

```
Power[Blank[], 2]
```

and then it does not match with `a*b` anymore. So one has to employ `HoldPattern`:

```
MatchQ[a*b, HoldPattern[Times[_, _]]]
```

> True

General advice: If anything goes wrong, always compare the `FullForm` of the expression and the pattern.

Comment: Got it! But it should say `MatchQ[a*b, HoldPattern[Times[_, _]]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you for pointing this out!